# How long will spaghetti and meat sauce last in the refrigerator?

Tags: pasta, culinary-uses

Today, I accidentally forgot that I had brought my lunch in - leftover spaghetti noodles and a meat sauce (sauce from a jar, meat cooked fresh and added to the sauce) that we had last night. They are in separate containers.

I'm going on an anniversary trip with my wife this weekend, so this lunch will be left in the office fridge for the next three days - one of which is a work day where people will be putting things in and taking things out of the fridge, but I won't be there.

Will my spaghetti and meat sauce lunch, that was cooked on Thursday, put in the company fridge Friday (today), and will be left in there until Tuesday (four days) still be safe to eat?  Or should I toss it when I get back?

Answer (score 0):

Sauce = 5 days

Meat (Left Overs) = 3 or 4 days

http://www.cbsnews.com/news/how-long-foods-stay-fresh-in-fridge/